# Weblogic 12c deployment error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I'm using ant script to build the application. This application is working under 9.2
`bea.lib=C:/bea92/weblogic92/server/lib` - ant code - working good but when I change to 12c 
lib folder `bea.lib=C:/bea12c/wlserver_12.1/server/lib`, it's giving me this error:

```
[javac] bad class file: C:\bea12c\wlserver_12.1\server\lib\..\..\..\modules\features\..\javax.servlet_2.0.0.0_3-0.jar(javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.class)
[javac] class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
[javac] Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
[javac] import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
[javac]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a library which has been compiled with `Java 6` but you have `JAVAC` lower than 1.6. I would suggest to upgrade your compiler to `1.6`.